# some urls are not opening in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

so problem is simple but i unable to find the solution . I am creating a portfolio plugin and trying to open the projects in the iframe to show responsive layout but problem is some urls are not opening in iframe nothing is showing when i hit these urls in iframe . Here is the [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojrudra/HnXFj/296/)

```
<a href="https://www.searchforenergy.com" target="myIframe">iframe2</a>
    <iframe src="" name = "myIframe"></iframe>
```

I want to check with jquery if it is able to open in iframe then ok otherwise the link will open in new tab instead .

Comment: Are the URL's that are NOT opening all 'https' and the ones that ARE opening all 'http', by any chance?

Comment: Refused to display 'https://www.searchforenergy.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). What you can do to solve this is add a header to your responses that allows cross origin resource sharing.

In apache you can do this by adding the following line in `httpd.conf` or any `.htaccess` files

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

[Source](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)

Comment: i used 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" in my wordpress plugin .htaccess file but it stopped my css.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.searchforenergy.com/. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.searchforenergy.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.

You can user jquery ajax error to check that url can accessible using javascript or not

```
$.ajax({

    url: "https://www.searchforenergy.com",
    dataType:'html',
    success: callback = function(data, textStatus, xhr)
    {
        console.log(data)
    },
    error: callback = function(data, textStatus, xhr)
    {
        console.log(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't see how ajax is going to be a very valid test

Comment: that's not much of an explanation and doesn't prove your case

Answer (score 0):

New solution after reading comment from charlietfl

HTML

```
<a id="btn" href="#">iframe2</a>
<iframe src="" id = "myIframe" onload="loadFrame(this)"></iframe>
```

Javascript

```
function loadFrame(frame) {
    if (!frame.contentDocument) {
        // code to open in tab
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $('#myIframe').attr('src', 'https://www.searchforenergy.com')
    });
});
```

Comment: this is working to open the link in other tab , but is there any solution so that i can open in i frame ???

Comment: you can not open other url due to Cross-Origin Request Blocked in frame till the domain is not permitted